# How to extend a functional using Hahn-Banach Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, hahn-banach-theorem

Hahn Banach Theorem:
Let $X$ be a normed Vector space and $U$ a subspace. For every linear continuous function $u':U \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$, there exists a continuous linear functional $x': X \rightarrow$ such that:
$x'_{|_U}=u'$ and $\lVert x' \rVert=\lVert u' \rVert$

$\lVert T \rVert=sup_{\lVert x \rVert \leq 1} \lVert Tx \rVert$

Now I want to try this out on an example:

Consider the Subspace $S={(x_1,x_2,x_3): x_1+2x_2=0,x_3=0}$
of the Banach space $(\mathbb{R^3},\lVert.\rVert_1)$.
With the functional $\phi((x_1,x_2,x_3)):=x_1$.

As far as I understood the proof, first I have to define $p(x)=\lVert u' \rVert \lVert x \rVert for x \in \mathbb{R}$
Then there exists a linear mapping $x':\mathbb{R}^3
 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $x'_{|_U}=u'$ and
$x'(x)\leq p(x)$ forall $x \in \mathbb{R}$.
Since we also have $x'(-x)\leq p(x)$ we get that
$|x'(x)|\leq \lVert u' \rVert \lVert x \rVert forall x \in \mathbb{R}^3$, this means $\lVert x' \rVert \leq \lVert u' \rVert$
On the other hand, $\lVert u' \rVert=sup_{u \in B}|u'(u)|=sup_{u \in B}{|x'(u)|} \leq sup_{x \in B}|x'(x)|=\lVert x' \rVert$

First, I determine $p$
$p(x)=\lVert u' \rVert \lVert x \rVert_1 =sup_{\lVert x \rVert \leq 1}\lVert u'x \rVert |x|=|x_1|(|x_1|+|x_2|+|x_3|)$

Now we need to choose (I think) $x'$ such that
$\lVert x' \rVert = \lVert u' \rVert$

$\lVert x' \rVert=sup_{\lVert x \rVert_1 \leq 1}\lVert x'(x) \rVert=|x_1|(|x_1|+|x_2|+|x_3|)=\lVert u' \rVert$

Now my question is, how do I exactly extend $u'$ to $x'$?

Isn't x' for example $x'(x_1,x_2,x_3)=x_1 x_2$

But shouldn't also $x'(x_1,x_2,x_3)=x_1 x_3$ work?
Why are there two extensions? Is my calculation/understanding wrong?

Comment: Hahn-Banach never promised a unique extension.

Comment: @stoic-santiago right, are the extensions at the bottom correct/did I calculate it correct?

Comment: Is your $x'$ at the last linear?

Comment: @Koro No, but how would I then extend the function?

Comment: You could consider the function $f(x_1,x_2,x_3)= x_1$ for all $(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in \mathbb R^3$. Note that it extends $\phi$.

Comment: @Koro Oh yeah, silly me. But is there a way on choosing those extensions? The first comment mentions that Hahn Banach does not guarantee unique extensions. For example, I think that $\phi(x_1,x_2,x_3)=x_1+x_3$ would be a second extension. Is this correct?

Comment: It is an extension but you want to preserve norm as well.